# How to display current Date after setting setMaxDate?

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I have set the maxDate to today date but it shows on January 1900 , I want to set the maxDate as Today and display today date on datepicker, please help.

```
startdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new 
                DatePickerDialog(AttendanceActivity.this, new 
                        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(i, i1, i2);
                mYearstart = i;
                mMonthstart = i1;
                mDaystart = i2;
                startDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            }
        }, mYearstart, mMonthstart, mDaystart);

        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate (System.currentTimeMillis());
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: `setMaxDate` does only set the maximum selectable date. I think you need another function.

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly? I can’t read it as it stands. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.. below code put into onCreate method.. or button click

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

 DatePickerDialog dialog =
new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
 dialog.show();
```

// this define in inside class..
     DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        // myCalendar your calendar object
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    }
};
```

try this to define into class..

```
 Calendar myCalendar;
int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.upload);
    Button selectUploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select_image);
    selectUploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            DatePickerDialog dialog =
                    new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity1.this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
       dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    mYear = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks,  I'm  getting this on mDateSetListener "Cannot resolve symbol 'mDateSetListener' " what should I do?

Comment: mDateSetListener object of DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() method.

Comment: The terrible `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I added  dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());  and it block the future date, this is what have been looking for .

Comment: you can set only this   dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: i update my answer and it block future date. it set before dialog show.